# How do I use LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE fro csv import in Wordpress as a custom plugin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have the code here working great on my server and mysql dB. It imports a large csv file (1000000 rows) into a table very fast.

I am trying to use the same code in a Wordpress environment. I have tried putting the php file with below code in the site root and then trying to view the page to run it, but it wont load - I believe its a Wordpress feature.

How can I access this page to run the import in Wordpress. The table exists on the WP databse ready for the import. Should I make a custom? plugin. I am new to Wordpress. Any help would be great.

```
$table='offers';
$file='xxx.csv';

$result1=mysqli_query($cons,"select count(*) count from $table");
$r1=mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
$count1=(int)$r1['count'];
usleep(mt_rand(100, 10000));
mysqli_query($cons, '
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "'.$file.'"
        INTO TABLE '.$table.'
        FIELDS TERMINATED by \',\'
        LINES TERMINATED BY \'\n\'
')or die(mysql_error());

$result2=mysqli_query($cons,"select count(*) count from $table");
$r2=mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
$count2=(int)$r2['count'];

$count=$count2-$count1;
etc..
```

Comment: So you're trying to add a CVS file to the same database as the Wordpress installation but in a custom table? And if you get an error what does it output?

Comment: 403 error when i try to view page. I will try by making a simple plugin.

Comment: Check file permissions, and are you using any Wordpress functions or its all just an import script? If it's all custom you should be able to just access the file directly, or create a plugin folder and an index.php file with you script, this is if it's all custom. But if you're using any of the Wordpress functions you could use the wpdb class and its functions. And if it's all bare you don't even have to use the Wordpress directory for this.